# Problems accessing PHP project in apache2

Tags: php, server, apache2

I am developing a platform and am using an open-source php project, I cloned it off github.
So, the main problem I've been having is with Apache2, for some reason even if I place the file containing my PhP project under var/www/html, I specified the config file of apache to read the php index, but it is not opening it. The only result I am getting is the welcome webpage of apache2. PHP is working just fine, since Phpmyadmin and the test website of php that I placed in the same /html works as well. Am I missing a configuration setting within apache?

I also enabled a custom config file for my page and added it to hosts here is the file I enabled within apache2:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin admin@moritologon.com
ServerName moritologon.com
DocumentRoot /home/Sistema_php/online-food-ordering-system-in-php-master/

<Directory /home/Sistema_php/online-food-ordering-system-in-php-master/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride all
            Require all granted
</Directory>

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

## vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you show us where you configured Apache to use the PHP file? Is your project currently in `/home/Sistema_php/online-food-ordering-system-in-php-master/` or `/var/www/html/` and what are the permissions of that folder or the files in it? Does the Apache error log (or access log) contain any hint? Do you have any other `ServerName moritologon.com` directives in any other Apache configuration files?

Comment: Do you run the `a2ensite` command to enable your site and then reload apache?